# Medal Of Honor: War Fighter Shore Leave Glitch?

Tags: medal-of-honor

I'm playing on XBOX 360 and just after you snipe all the guys off the roof the chopper flies away and my guy just lies there? Is anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked it up online and [looks like a glitch on all platforms](http://answers.ea.com/t5/Medal-of-Honor-Warfighter/Cannot-continue/m-p/133856).

I found a work around for it though. If you are affected by the glitch, make sure you take out the last two snipers (that try to take down the chopper) before they can move. As soon as I did this, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a glitch. You have to aim high because the bullet drops as it flies. When aiming at the two guys on the tower, aim at the lower one — that worked for me.

Comment: i know that i meant after you have killed all the people, and the chopper leaves, you should read the question properly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is really glitched or people aren't taking into account bullet drop, saw a YouTube video the other day of someone claimiing the game was glitched and what ended up happening is he wasn't using the secondary sniper zoom by clicking down on the right analog, and he was centering the crosshair on the guys with the RPGs (not taking into account bullet drop), I've not failed this once.

so remember, click left analog to steady shot, use right analog to zoom further, and account for bullet drop

also, make sure you have the latest update to the game if it was addressed pre-release in a patch

Comment: Could you link to said YouTube video, please?